# Relationship design for auto parts store database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a design database for an autoparts store (this is a project school). For the moment, I'm not sure if the relationship model especially in `MODEL`, `MAKE`, `BRAND` is correct (I really have no experience about this area).

I'm not an expert in this area, so I need some help.

```
create database AutoParts2

use AutoParts2
go

create table Make
(
MakeID int not null identity(1,1),
Name varchar(50) not null,
constraint PK_Make primary key (MakeID)
)

create table Model
(
ModelID int not null identity(1,1),
MakeID int not null,
Name varchar(50) not null,
constraint PK_Model primary key (ModelID),
constraint FK_Model_Make foreign key (MakeID)
references Make(MakeID)
)

create table [Year]
(
YearID tinyint not null identity(1,1),
Name char(4) not null,
constraint PK_Year primary key (YearID)
)

create table Model2Year
(
Model2YearID int not null identity(1,1),
ModelID int not null,
YearID tinyint not null,
constraint PK_Model2Year primary key (Model2YearID),
constraint FK_Model2Year_Model foreign key (ModelID)
references Model(ModelID),
constraint FK_Model2Year_Year foreign key (YearID)
references [Year](YearID)
)

create table Category
(
CategoryID tinyint not null identity(1,1),
Name varchar(30) not null,
constraint PK_Category primary key (CategoryID)
)

create table Subcategory
(
SubcategoryID tinyint not null identity(1,1),
CategoryID tinyint not null,
Name varchar(30) not null,
constraint PK_Subcategory primary key (SubcategoryID),
constraint FK_Subcategory_Category foreign key (SubcategoryID)
references Category(CategoryID)
)

create table Model2Year2Category
(
Model2Year2CategoryID int not null identity(1,1),
Model2YearID int not null,
CategoryID tinyint not null,
constraint PK_Model2Year2Category primary key (Model2Year2CategoryID),
constraint FK_Model2Year2Category_Model2Year foreign key (Model2YearID)
references Model2Year(Model2YearID),
constraint FK_Model2Year2Category_Category foreign key (CategoryID)
references Category(CategoryID)
)

create table Brand
(
BrandID int not null identity(1,1),
Name varchar(50) not null,
constraint PK_Brand primary key (BrandID)
)

create table Brand2Subcategory
(
Brand2SubcategoryID int not null identity(1,1),
BrandID int not null,
SubcategoryID int not null,
constraint PK_Brand2Subcategory primary key (Brand2SubcategoryID),
constraint FK_Brand2Subcategory_Brand foreign key (BrandID)
references Brand(BrandID),
constraint FK_Brand2Subcategory_Subcategory foreign key (SubcategoryID)
references Subcategory(SubcategoryID)
)

create table Part
(
PartID int not null identity(1,1),
Name varchar(50) not null,
BrandID int not null,
PartNumber varchar(50) not null,
Description varchar(200),
constraint PK_Part primary key (PartID),
constraint FK_Part_Brand foreign key (BrandID)
references Brand(BrandID)
)

create table Model2Year2Part
(
Model2Year2PartID int not null identity(1,1),
Model2YearID int not null,
PartID int not null,
constraint PK_Model2Year2Part primary key (Model2Year2PartID),
constraint FK_Model2Year2Part_Model2Year foreign key (Model2YearID)
references Model2Year(Model2YearID),
constraint FK_Model2Year2Part_Part foreign key (PartID)
references Part(PartID)
)

create table Brand2Subcategory2Part
(
Brand2Subcategory2PartID int not null identity(1,1),
Brand2SubcategoryID int not null,
PartID int not null,
constraint PK_Brand2Subcategory2Part primary key (Brand2Subcategory2PartID),
constraint FK_Brand2Subcategory2Part_Brand2Subcategory foreign key (Brand2SubcategoryID)
references Brand2Subcategory(Brand2SubcategoryID),
constraint FK_Brand2Subcategory2Part_Part foreign key (PartID)
references Part(PartID)
)
```

Answer (score 4):

You have all the tables you need and you have the many-to-many relationships correct, I think.

I'd suggest that you add a Parent field to Category and then create a hierarchy of categories instead of having a Category table with a single Subcategory table.

```
create table Category(
    CategoryId int not null identity(1,1),
    ParentCategoryId int null,
    CategoryName nvarchar(100) not null,
    primary key (CategoryId))
```

As a point of style, I'd name the many-to-many tables with underscores instead of numbers, i.e. `Model_Year_Part`.

Note that I used nvarchar instead of varchar.

If you ask a question on StackExchange for a school project, don't forget the citation if you use the answers! It's okay to ask but never to plagiarise.

Comment: Yes, the initial design seems mostly there, although he _may_ want to add at least one more unique constraint on `Part` - `[BrandId, PartNumber]`.  And yeah, the `2`s as seperators is confusing - what if there was a table named `Model2` (for whatever bizarre reason...)?

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider the following things:

- Are you sure that you need the `Year` table? You could store the year in the `Model2Year` table directly.
- I would omit the `Model2Year.Model2YearID` attribute. Instead of this I'd use a compound primary key `(ModelID, Year)` or `(ModelID, YearID)`.
- Is it possible that, for example, a specific model is in `categoryX` in 1999 and it's in `categoryY` in 2000? If not, connect the `Model` and the `Category` table with a `model_to_category` helper table (`(ModelId, CategoryId)` is the primary key) instead of the current `Model2Year2Category` table.

It's not obvious what you store in these tables. Provide some example for every table and I'll update this answer. For example, does `Category` store car categories or part categories?